# exponential distribution and the gamma function

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution, digamma-function

I don't find the relationship between the expected value (theoretical) of an exponential distributed variable and the gamma function. I work on the paper Moments of the Log ACD model from Luc Bauwens(2008). And on page six they estimate the expected value form an exponential distributed variable with a gamma function.There is some further context, for example how the part with epsilon^(alpha*beta^j) stems from, but this is not the crucial part and certainly not why I struggle to understand the relationship to the equality of equation 3 in the picture. Alpha and beta are strict smaller than one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZRF4.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF of $\epsilon \sim \exp(1)$ is $e^{-x}$ for $x \geq 0$. Hence $E[\epsilon^\gamma] = \int_0^\infty x^\gamma e^{-x}\,dx = \Gamma[1+\gamma]$ by the definition of the gamma function.

Comment: well thank you very much